# How do i make this javascript function run from server side in if else c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

i am trying to get JS run from server side in c#. basicaly everytime the login creditentials are wrong it should call the js from the else loop
this is the server side code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            co.Connection = cn;
            co.CommandText = "select * from reg where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
            ds = co.ExecuteReader();
            if (ds.Read())
            {
                // co.CommandText = "select * from res where Id='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
                Response.Redirect("http://localhost:50892/home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //lblerror.Text = "Incorrect Id and Password";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Response.Write(e1.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is the front end code. i have already made an alert for forget password and i am trying to get the same alert for forgot pass. i am also attaching an image of how the first alert looks[image]

```
<div id="myAlert2" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
                                <a id="linkClose2" href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                                <strong>Info!</strong> invalid id or pass
                            </div>

    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {

            $('#myAlert2').show('fade');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#myAlert2').hide('fade');
            }, 2000);


        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                $('#myAlert').show('fade');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
                }, 2000);

            });

            $('#linkClose').click(function () {
                $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
            });

        });

    </script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js">

    </script>
```

Comment: One problem is that `myFunction()` is inside your document.ready block, so it doesn't have global scope. Therefore it won't be accessible to the call to it which is generated by the .NET code. You need to move it outside that block, it doesn't need to be there anyway. The second issue I can see is that javascript is case-sensitive, so `MyFunction()` will not match `myFunction`. I would expect you are seeing errors in your browser's Console which would be telling you these things - did you check?

Comment: P.S. Putting `$('#linkClose').click(function () {` inside the myFunction is not a good practice - you don't want to keep adding multiple click event handlers every time myFunction is executed. That handler should be inside document.ready directly.

Comment: Hello ADyson thank you for your reply. I made the changes you suggested but it still is not working. This is pastebin link for the updated code https://pastebin.com/ThYDUDsK

Comment: If you have an update, please use the "edit" button below your question to make changes. Please don't post the code in another site instead.

Comment: Anyway, "not working" isn't a sufficient description of your problem. we need more precise details. e.g. Are there any errors in the browser console? Have you tried debugging to see if `myFunction()` is actually executed or not?

Comment: P.S. From a user experience point of view, I don't think showing the alert for 2 seconds and then hiding it again is very good. 2 seconds is not long. What if the user gets distracted and turns away from the screen for a moment? It happens all the time. In that case, they would not see the alert, and would not understand what the problem was. Personally I would not hide the alert at all. It's not getting in the way of anything, so why not just show it permanently? Then there is no danger of the user not seeing it.

Comment: P.P.S. This is a separate problem: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using C# / ADO.NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Hello again ADyson i have edited my question with the updated code. I am still learning programming and i am thankful that you are helping me find mistakes in my code. Yes i am getting a error in my browder "Reference Error: myFunction is not defined" .

Comment: The most likely reason for that now is that the `<script` block inserted by ASP.NET which makes the call to `myFunction()` is inserted into the page _before_ the script block where the function is defined. Browsers load and execute a script block as soon as they see it in the HTML, so if that script refers to a function in a script block which hasn't been loaded yet, you'll get a problem. You'll need to define the function right at the start of your page, I would think.

Comment: Okay, i defined it at the start and its working now. Thank you very much ADyson for your help. ALSO where can i learn about passing sanitised data into sql ?

Comment: As I said, you can find it at the link I gave you in my comment (http://bobby-tables.com) - there are examples for many different languages and libraries, including the C#/ADO.NET combination - look at the left-side menu. And you can get more examples in dozens of other places - just search for "ADO.NET parameterised query" on google. If you want more general information about the problem of SQL Injection just google "SQL injection" :-)